# Order of adjectives: same category

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adjective-position

I teach English, and regularly introduce students to "OSASCOMP", the mnemonic to help them with the "royal order of adjectives".

This is fine, for adjectives in the categories described by this rule (opinion, size, age, shape, colour, origin, material, purpose), but one question has stumped me. How do we determine adjective order, for multiple adjectives within the same category?

If I refer to my "fabulous, amazing, beautiful husband", will he be bowled over by the compliment, or aghast at my grammar?

Comment: Fine? 'Who's afraid of the bad, big wolf?'? A _dumb big booster_?

Answer (score 1):

Being bowled over by the compliment and aghast at the grammar do not seem to be mutually exclusive. But adjectives from many of the OSASCOMP categories are indeed mutually exclusive.

Take *size* and *material* for example. You cannot have *a big, little box* or *a leather, woollen jacket*. So the question about the order of adjectives within such categories generally does not arise.

But *opinion* adjectives such as *fabulous, amazing, beautiful* are not mutually exclusive (although they may be synonymous). And they can be arranged in any order you like.